# Vectors must be the same length

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This code works on state `new_f([0 0 0 0 0 0 0],5,1000)`
but if we try `new_f([0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1],5,1000)` it gives  Vectors must be the same length.
Which is really strange since I think I'm doing find, because I'm using t (bit duration) and tsym for 2 bit duration and `Rb` is the bit rate.
I took care of special case if the data ended with one I add zeros and increase n (Data length)

```
    function new_f(Data,v,Rb)
  n=length(Data);
  if(Data(n)==1)
    Data=[Data 0];
    n=n+1;
  end
  Tb=1/Rb;
  Ts=Tb/1200;
  t=0:Ts:Tb-Ts;
  pulse=[ones(1,length(t)/2) zeros(1,length(t)/2) ];
  A0=1;
  A01=2;
  A11=2;
  ph0=0;
  ph10=0;
  ph11=pi;
  f=1000;
  ph11=pi;
  tsym=0:Ts:2*Tb-Ts;

  D0=A0*sin(2*pi*f*t+ph0);
  D10=A01*sin(2*pi*f*tsym+ph10);
  D11=A11*sin(2*pi*f*tsym+ph11);
  clock=[];
  Dout=[];
  Dout2=[];

  for i=1:1:n
  clock=[clock pulse];
  end
  for i=1:1:n

if(Data(i)==0 )
    Dout=[Dout D0];

    continue;
end

    if(Data(i)==1 && Data(i+1)==0)
    Dout=[Dout D10 ];
    i=i+1
  continue;
    end

    Dout=[Dout D11];
    i=i+1;
    end



  T=0:Ts:n*Tb-Ts;
  subplot(2,1,1)
  plot(T,clock);
  grid on
  axis([0 n*Tb-Ts -0.1 1.1 ])
  subplot(2,1,2)
  plot(T,Dout);
  grid on
  axis([0 n*Tb-Ts -v-0.1*v v+0.1*v])


  end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know at what line you get the error message.

Comment: @CrisLuengo third line from the bottom at ( plot(T,Dout); )

Comment: That means that `T` and `Dout` are not the same length. Seems like `Dout` has `n` elements, and `T` has many more. The definition of `T` is probably wrong. I don’t know what it is supposed to do, so can’t help fix it. Also, the `i=i+1` statement inside the loop over `i` is meaningless. Loops in MATLAB work differently than in C.

Comment: @CrisLuengo
mmm....how  can we control the loop increment in matlab?

Comment: you have to use a `while i<=n` loop. `for` iterates through a list, takes each element in turn, never skips one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks To @CrisLuengo
according to CrisLuengo we can't control the for loop increment in matlab and solution is using while statement

```
 function line_coding(Data,v,Rb)
    n=length(Data);
    if(n>1)
    if(Data(n)==1 && Data(n-1)==0)
      Data=[Data 0];
      n=n+1;
    end;

    else
    if(Data(n)==1)
  Data=[Data 0];
  n=n+1;

end;
Tb=1/Rb;
Ts=Tb/1200;
t=0:Ts:Tb-Ts;
pulse=[ones(1,length(t)/2) zeros(1,length(t)/2) ];
A0=1;
A01=2;
A11=2;
ph0=0;
ph10=0;
ph11=pi;
f=1000;
ph11=pi;
tsym=0:Ts:2*Tb-Ts;

D0=A0*sin(2*pi*f*t+ph0);
D10=A01*sin(2*pi*f*tsym+ph10);
D11=A11*sin(2*pi*f*tsym+ph11);
clock=[];
Dout=[];
Dout2=[];
%   a=1;
%   b=1;
temp =1 ;
for i=1:1:n
clock=[clock pulse];
end
j=1;
while j<=n
    if(Data(j)==0)
        Dout=[Dout D0];
        j=j+1;
    else
       if(Data(j+1)==1)
           Dout=[Dout D11]
       else 
           Dout=[Dout D10]
       end
       j=j+2
    end

end;


T=0:Ts:n*Tb-Ts;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(T,clock);
grid on
axis([0 n*Tb-Ts -0.1 1.1 ])
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(T,Dout);
grid on
axis([0 n*Tb-Ts -v-0.1*v v+0.1*v])


end
```